# Getting 500 Internal Server Error after Publish

Tags: .net, publish

I published my Web Api project on sub domain. But whenever I am trying to make a call, getting 500 Internal error. It works locally fine, but not working on the server.

Any guess, what should I need to be taking care off?

Comment: What does it say if enable remote errors?

Comment: Check the event log on the server box.

Comment: where can I find that ?

Comment: there is nothing in the log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my experience, but most of the time I got error 500, it's when I don't have read/write permissions on certain folders on the server. Be aware, IIS is running with “network_service” account and not your user account.

Another source of error can be not changed DataSourceString. You have an option to change it during publishing (If you use Visual publish system, if not change it by hand)
I think there is about 90% chances your problem is one of these two.

Feel free to comment, so I can respond and assist you

Comment: Thank you very much. There was a problem in the DataSourceString. It's finally working now.